# How does one change the value of a global variable in a function to be used later on?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to create a weather application, and in order to do that I need to parse out JSON. This works, (which I know because I tested it by printing), but I cannot change the value of the data I get to an already initialized global variable. A similar question was asked before, but even using the provided answers, I was not able to solve my own problem.

The following lines are where I initialize my global variables:

```
var currentTemperature = 88
var currentTime = 789
```

And the following Lines are where I parse the JSON and test by printing in my viewDidLoad function:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c269e5928cbdadde5e9d4040a5bd4833/42.1784,-87.9979")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        }
        else {

            if let content = data {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let jsonCurrently = json["currently"] as? NSDictionary {

                        if let jsonCurrentTime = jsonCurrently["time"] {

                            currentTime = jsonCurrentTime as! Int
                            print(currentTime)

                        }

                        if let jsonCurrentTemperature = jsonCurrently["temperature"] {

                            currentTemperature = jsonCurrentTemperature as! Int
                            print(currentTemperature)


                        }



                    }

                } catch {

                }

            }

        }

    }

    task.resume()
```

I use the global variables when setting the text of a label in a different class: (however, only the initial value I set to the variable shows up, not the one from the parsed JSON)

```
let currentTemperatureLabel: UILabel = {
    //label of the current temperature
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = String(currentTemperature) + "°"
    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 150/255, green: 15/255, blue: 15/255, alpha: 0.8)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Damascus", size: 130)
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 130, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
    return label
}()
```

The JSON example request can be found here: https://darksky.net/dev/docs#api-request-types

No matter what I do, I am not able to use the data from the JSON when I attempt to access the two global variables mentioned before.

Comment: Is that all that you are doing to init your global variables? Do you store them in a static instance? How are you trying to access them later on?

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON you’re parsing?

Comment: As I am new to Xcode, I really don't know how to answer your first 2 questions Shamas, but I updated the post to answer your third question and to answer  your question ColGraff.

Answer (score 2):

```
var currentTemperature : Double = 88
var currentTime = 789

//...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/c269e5928cbdadde5e9d4040a5bd4833/42.1784,-87.9979")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        }
        else {

            if let content = data {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let jsonCurrently = json["currently"] as? NSDictionary {

                        if let jsonCurrentTime = jsonCurrently["time"] as? Int {

                            currentTime = jsonCurrentTime
                            print(currentTime)

                        }

                        if let jsonCurrentTemperature = jsonCurrently["temperature"] as? Double {

                            currentTemperature = jsonCurrentTemperature
                            print(currentTemperature)


                        }



                    }

                } catch {

                }

            }

        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

I did these edits above to your code:

- Changed your `currentTemperature` to be Double (Look at your JSON response to see what kind of response you get and what kind of data type it can be)
- When trying to get "time" and "temperature" added optional wrapping to get the data correctly from the response with correct data type so that when assigning to your variables you wont need to do explicit unwrapping

**EDIT:**
Updated answer based on your comment about the global variables not being part of the class

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I think you misunderstood my question. When I said global variables, I meant variables that were not initialized in a specific class, rather were initialized outside of the classes. I think for this reason, when I use the "self.", I get an error as those variables don't exist inside the class, and therefore means I can't use the "self." Additionally, in case this wasn't clear, the print statements were only included by me in order to test if the problem was with the parsing of the JSON, or with the variables (I realized the problem was with the variables).

Comment: Yeah I do understand the print statements are for your debugging purposes, however if those two variables are global variables in terms of not being part of the class (I assumed it's part of the class) then the code above i posted still should work, just remove self (see edit), it would still work since i tested this in playgrounds as well

Comment: Ok, but for some reason if I add a print statement at the end of my viewDidLoad function, that prints currentTemperature, it still ends up printing the original value of currentTemperature (88) even though the two print statements inside the JSON parsing prints the correct values.

Comment: You do realize that your line of code:

"let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with ..."

is an asynchronous call right?

See this apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask

your closure is your completion handler which gets called once the data you requested from the url has been downloaded